# Deserialize object without implementation

Tags: java, serialization

Long story short, I serialize a java object and saved it on the database.

From another java app I want get that information (I was able as a byte[]), but in this java app I only have the interfaces and got exceptions when trying to deserialize it back.

My main goal is to deserialize it into a json, not necesary into the same or a java object.

**Is there a way to accomplish this? with some kind of proxies to mock the concrete class?**

Thanks!

Comment: For Java to be able to deserialize it must have source code of that class. So you'd better serialize and store JSON in your database

Comment: For use json I need the class reference as a property to then deserialize, I don't want to annotate all my classes with @json... properties. Do you know an option for the ObjectMapper  to automatically add a class reference property?

Comment: `My main goal is to deserialize it into a json, not necesary into the same or a java object.` If you save JSON into database then you just need to execute simple `SELECT` to get JSON and start using it.
If you need to recreate Java objects than both application that serializes and application that deserializes should have java code of that concrete class which was serialized

Comment: Yes, in the first app I need to serialize it in the original java objects, in the second is not mandatory.